# How to make the div container the exact dimensions as the image inside

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to make the div size the exact dimensions as the image inside of it. I need this done because I am trying to put a box-shadow that borders the image, and with my current code, the box shadow borders the div surrounding the image. This is causing the box-shadow to be offset from the image. Below is my .css and .html code:

```
.css:

    .image__container--one {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-top: 2rem;
    }
    
    #image-one {
      height: 60rem;
      width: auto;
      margin-right: 5rem;
      display: block;
      transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    
    #image-two {
      height: auto;
      width: 60rem;
      align-self: flex-start;
      margin-left: 5rem;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 10px rgb(43, 43, 43);
    }
    
    .img-wrapper {
      overflow: hidden;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 10px rgb(43, 43, 43);
    }
    
    #image-one:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    }
    
    .html:
    <body>
        <main class="container">
          <div class="container__main">
            <div class="container__main--title">
              <h1>John Doe Photography</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="image__container--one">
              <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="/portfolio/vertical4.jpg"
                  alt="India culutre"
                  id="image-one"
                />
              </div>
              <img
                src="/portfolio/horizontal2.jpg"
                alt="Camel image"
                id="image-two"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </body>
```

Comment: For the image use `object-fit: cover;`. In this way you will make the image cover the div.

Comment: This didn't work @Azu

Comment: try adding `height: fit-content;` `width: fit-content;` or `block-size: fit-content;` to your image container.

Comment: No change. The padding on the right hand side of the div (as seen in the picture) will not go away no matter what I try. I am thinking this may not be possible since the image scales on hover. @Martin

Comment: @Austin then size the image according to the container instead of the reverse and your problem is solved.  `object-fit: cover`. Will do this for you, as @Azu also mentioned previously. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: actually this did work, I forgot to remove the margin, this solution is correct @Martin

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure it out what u want to accomplish.

1. Box you transforming should be the same box (element) that have box-shadow property.
2. Container that holds your elements, that will be scaled after hover should  have some padding (space) to fit scaled elements and shadow

So in your case would be something like this snippet

```css
.image__container--one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4rem;
}
    
#image-one {
  height: 6rem;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

.img-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 10px rgb(43, 43, 43);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.img-wrapper:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <main class="container">
          <div class="container__main">
            <div class="container__main--title">
              <h1>John Doe Photography</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="image__container--one">
              <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img
                  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
                  alt="India culutre"
                  id="image-one"
                />
                </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </body>
```

Comment: this didnt work

Comment: @Austin you need to be more descriptive then. What do you want? When you run the snippet, it illustrates what you're asking. So "what" didn't work for you? "What" do you actually need then?

Comment: @Martin  When I copied this code, the box shadow still borders the div and the image is smaller then the div, making the box-shadow appear offset to the image. This soultion also caused the image to overflow. See the image I attached.

Comment: @Austin in my code snippet it does not. Maybe you are doing something wrong ?.
Read what I wrote. Scale image to parent div via setting `height: 100%` or `width: 100%` Or other wat as I did in my snippet make wrapper to adjust to image size. Maybe you have some overriding styles in your project ?